# checking if a value exists in a gridview using c#

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I have a C# Windows Application (.net 4) and it looks something like this:
It runs a query and populates the gridview by running my view.

How do I check for a certain value from the query results? and if it exists then play a sound?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CREATE TIMER
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //SET UP THE TIMER
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Interval = (1000 * 30 * 1);
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();   
}

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Run the Query every 30 SECONDS");

        //run the query now
        string ConnectionString = "Data Source=C;Initial Catalog=tickets;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM [tickets].[dbo].[TicketView]", Conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DA.Fill(dt);

        if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }

            BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
            BS.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = BS;
            bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BS;
        }
```

I thought about writing the following loop:

Ticket exists should return a value or zero if it doesn't find anything in the gridview and value or 1 if it does. I want to check for company code. (`[COMPANYCODE]`) << (im stuck on this part)

```
int ticketExists;
    while (ticketExists > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Play a sound as ticket exists!");
        // Write the index to the screen.
        Console.WriteLine(ticketExists);
        // Increment the variable.
        ticketExists++;
    }
```

I figured out how to play a sound if anyone wants to know:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The sound will play after this message!!");

        using (var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav")) {
            soundPlayer.Play(); // can also use soundPlayer.PlaySync()
        }

    }
```

Comment: If your `ticketExists` is greater than zero the loop will never end. Are you sure you have to do that? Secondly if you want to check some value in database if it exists then why dont you do that in the query itself?

Comment: I need logic to write to check if the value does exist then play a sound. I need help writing a loop i think?

Comment: What is the value you want to check? Which column of the gridview? Can you do simple select on the gridviews datasource instead of looping through all the records in the grid view? something like `var records = from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where d.Field<string>(0).Contains("Somevalue")
                          select d;`